# Yii2 get request url

Tags: php, yii2

Как сделать понятный url при get запросе с помощью ActiveForm

Сейчас url выглядит так:
/work/dashboard?DashboardFilter%5Bspeciality%5D=&DashboardFilter%5BforYou%5D=0&DashboardFilter%5BonlySafe%5D=0&DashboardFilter%5BonlySafe%5D=1

Как сделать что б был вот такой:
/work/dashboard?forYou=0&onlySafe=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Указать имя поля при генерации

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'forYou')->checkbox(['name' => 'forYou']) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'onlySafe')->checkbox(['name' => 'onlySafe']) ?>
```

А в моделе поиска при загрузке данных в указать имя формы `''`

```
$this->load($params, '');
```